# bindParam & bindValue don't work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindvalue

I'm trying to make a register/login system. To check if usernames and email addresses aren't used, I use this :

```
$username = $_POST['uLogin'];
    $usernameLC = strtolower($username);
    $query1 = $db0->query("SELECT userLogin FROM tbuser WHERE userLogin=':login';");
    $query1->bindValue(":login", $usernameLC, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

But it doesn't work. I can create as much users with the same username as I want. By extension, it also won't let me connect onto the website as it doesn't bind values or anything, so it can't compare my username to the one in the DB.

Verifying if a username is not taken worked when I used it like this

```
$username = $_POST['uLogin'];
    $usernameLC = strtolower($username);
    $query1 = $db0->query("SELECT userLogin FROM tbuser WHERE userLogin='$usernameLC';");
```

But it isn't the proper way to go :/

Can anybody help ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, if you're going to prepare, use `->prepare()`, and remove quotes in your named placeholders, they don't need to have that:

```
$query1 = $db0->prepare("SELECT userLogin FROM tbuser WHERE userLogin= :login");
```

Then `$query1->execute()`, the prepared statement after the binding, so all in all:

```
$username = $_POST['uLogin'];
$usernameLC = strtolower($username);
$query1 = $db0->prepare('SELECT userLogin FROM tbuser WHERE userLogin = :login'); // prepare
$query1->bindValue(':login', $usernameLC, PDO::PARAM_STR); // bind
$query1->execute(); // execute
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice them not preparing. Good catch there Ghost ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- funny thing is, i just noticed it while fixing the indentation of the answer lol :D

Comment: I was typing mine at the (same) time and didn't notice your answer. OP should choose yours to accept. *Cheers* I just made an additional note at the bottom of mine.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. When logging in though, comparing submitted password to the password in DB returns false. I try stocking the received password in `$_SESSION['test']` to see what it gets and `print_r($_SESSION);` returns me this : 
`Array ( [test] => Array ( [userPwd] => test12 [0] => test12 ) )`
(test12 is my password, userPwd is the password Field in the db) Any idea ? ^^'

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments and that would qualify as *another* question @BatteMan

Comment: @BatteMan seems you're just saving plain naked password on DB, i'd suggest use `password_hash` with `password_verify` for this, but for right now, you could just add that into binding in your select. or fetch the selected row and compare against the saved session values

Comment: @Ghost Indeed. I've made an additional edit in my answer in regards to all that. I hope it serves them well and that they have seen it also.

Answer (score 6):

They're not working because your binded values contain quotes; remove them.

```
userLogin=':login'
```

as

```
userLogin=:login
```

> *"Verifying if a username is not taken worked when I used it like this"*

```
WHERE userLogin='$usernameLC'
```

- You need to remove the quotes in the bind as already stated on top, and make sure you're using PDO to connect with, as stated below; **if** that is the case.

Using `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` would have signaled the syntax errors.

Read up on how to use prepared statements in PDO, to prepare and execute:

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

---

***An insight:***

Make sure you are indeed using a PDO connection rather than a `mysqli`-based (it's unknown). I see these types of questions often, where OP's use `mysqli_` to connect with and querying with PDO.

Those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.

- [**Connecting through PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) on PHP.net

If you're using `mysqli_` to connect with:

- [See mysqli prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and how to use them.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors, if any in regards to your POST arrays, or other possible errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Edit:**

> *"Thanks, it works great. When logging in though, comparing submitted password to the password in DB returns false. I try stocking the received password in $_SESSION['test'] to see what it gets and print_r($_SESSION); returns me this : Array ( [test] => Array ( [userPwd] => test12 [0] => test12 ) ) (test12 is my password, userPwd is the password Field in the db) Any idea ? ^^"*

In regards to a comment you left about using passwords.

It seems you are storing passwords in plain text, rather than a hash. This is highly discouraged, as well as being stored in sessions; **a very bad idea**.

- [**Read up on sessions hijacking**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

See this Q&A on Stack on hashed passwords:

- Q: [Php 5.5 And Pdo Login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25072383/)
- A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023211/

Using PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function.

For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

A note about the column type and length when storing a hashed password.

- The password column should be `VARCHAR`.
- It should also be long enough to store the hash.
- Using `VARCHAR(255)` is best.

Comment: Looks like I pissed somebody off in the last 1/2 hour and downvoting me in spite. You're going to lead a very miserable life my friend.